# Beamer presentation table of content - completely hide other section and only show current section and subsections

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

The structure is as below

> Section 1
>
> Section 2
>
> subsection 1
>
> subsection 2
>
> subsection 3
>
> Section 3
>
> Section 4
>
> Section 5
>
> Section 6

and in a slide, I would show as below to completely hide secion 1, 4,5,6. Is there anyway that beamer can do it?

> Section 2
>
> subsection 1
>
> subsection 2
>
> subsection 3

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I agree with samcarter that a MWE would be nice. Anyway I want to point you to the combination of `\section*{}` and `\stepcounter{section}`.

Comment: @user124577 much, much easier :) I have two solutions in mind, but first I need a MWE to see where exactly this page should be.

Comment: Please provide details of your set-up.  The answer will depend on which beamer theme you use.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on where you want to show the toc of section 2. As you did not show us a MWE or give us any other information, here some possibilities for places where I could imagine one would want to place this toc:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[sections=2]
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}\frame{}

\section{Section 2}\frame{}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[currentsection,sectionstyle=show/hide]
\end{frame}

\subsection{subsection 1}\frame{}
\subsection{subsection 2}\frame{}
\subsection{subsection 3}\frame{}
\section{Section 3}\frame{}
\section{Section 4}\frame{}
\section{Section 5}\frame{}
\section{Section 6}\frame{}


\end{document}
```